# Plugin for public folder/files access for zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a Zend Framework plugin that handles access to public files and folders?
For example : User cant open that public folder/file whenever the current logged on user has no access to that file.
User Access will come from a database.

Tried searching but can't see any.Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no such component out of box. But you can implement using [ZEND_ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html).

1) Disable public access to all files/folders. (Don't serve them thorough web server)
2) Serve all files/folders through zend framework with the help of zend_acl.